# Remove empty data using a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the original data as shown in the Yellow Table and I would like to create a new table referencing it, but ignoring the rows in which the participants have not answered any questions, as shown in the Red Table.
I need this to be dynamic as the number of questions is unknown.

Currently, I have this formula which removes the empty rows, but it gives me duplicates for the question ids.
`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDIRECT("A"&SMALL(IF(LEN($B$2:$E$11)=0,"",ROW($H$2:$H$11)),ROW(A2))), ""))`

Example Data, please reference this

[image]

Please could someone help me :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({A:E, TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:E),,9^9)))}, 
 "where Col6 is not null", 1), 9^9, COLUMNS(A:E)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, would it be possible to do something like this `=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({A:E, TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:E),,9^9)))}, 
 "where Col2 AND Col3 AND Col4 is not null", 1), 9^9, COLUMNS(A:E)))`

Comment: I used your initial query and found my solution `=ArrayFormula(INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({A:E, TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:E),,9^9)))}, 
 "where Col2 is not null or Col3 is not null or Col4 is not null or  Col5 is not null", 1), 9^9, COLUMNS(A:E))))`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the solution already provided, you can also take a coding approach to this and make use of Apps Script:

#### Snippet

```
function deleteEmptyRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID").getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
  var noRows = ss.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  for (let i = 1; i<noRows; i++) {
    if (ss.getRange(i,2).getValue() == "" && ss.getRange(i,3).getValue() == "" && ss.getRange(i,4).getValue() == "" && ss.getRange(i,5).getValue() == "") {
        ss.deleteRow(i); 
    }
  }
}
```

The script above gets the data from the wanted spreadsheet and if all the cells from each row are empty, then this row is being removed using the `deleteRow` method.

#### Before executing the script

[image: sheet before executing the script]

#### After executing the script

[image: sheet after executing the script]

#### Reference

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - deleteRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition).

Comment: Thanks so much for this response. I'm trying to avoid using code as the sheet will be referencing another sheet so I want it to be dynamically updated.

Comment: You can manage this easily by making use of [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).